# Moment Generating Function of a r.v $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(W)$ given $W \sim \text{Exponential}(\beta)$

Tags: probability

$W$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\beta$. Given $W$, the distribution of $Y$ is Poisson with parameter $W$.
So $\displaystyle \Pr(Y=j|W=w) = \frac {e^{-w}w^j} {j!}$ , for $j=0,1,2, \ldots$
Show that the MGF of $Y$ is $\displaystyle M_Y(t)= \frac {\beta} {\beta-e^t+1}$

I tried finding $E(Y)$ first and the deriving the MGF of $Y$ from it, but I'm stuck...

Comment: First, you need to define which of the competing definitions of the Exponential distribution you are using (rate parameter, or mean parameter). Your question is assuming 'rate', but this is not stated. Second, then find the Exponential parameter mix of a Poisson distribution ... and then find its mgf.

Comment: I have no clue how to find the exponential parameter mix of a Poisson distribution. The question has a hint that suggests I "condition on W", which is why i tried to find E(Y) first, eventually becoming considerably more confused...

Comment: For parameter mixture distributions, see, for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution

Comment: thank you BGM for the editing suggestions.
@ wolfies. Thanks for the suggestions. I wasn't able to extract much help from the wiki page. Is there a link to an example that you know of, or better yet, could you show me how to do this? Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: If it is a homework problem, or exercise, the value is in doing it oneself. If this is part of your course, then that material should be covered (or follow the wiki link and do your own research) ... you now have the structure as to how to proceed.

Comment: It's homework, and I have never seen an example of any such thing before. If there is any value in trying, I've put over 3 hours now into researching this to no avail. It seems at this point, that for me, there will be more value in observing a similar example or a solution...
The wiki link contains symbols that I don't know know.
This course I'm taking has as a prereq only elementary probability, while in fact, all other students has taken courses in stats and probability, which has put me in an uncomfortable spot - on top of this, there is no textbook, just scattered notes from lectures :(

Comment: Do you know the definition of MGF? Do you know how to compute an expectation $E[g(X)]$ for both continuous and discrete random variables? Do you know the law of total expectation / double expectation formula?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. If it just asked to find E(Y)=E(g(W)) it'd be fine. I'm lost at how to use the double expectation law on the MGF. That is: My(t)=E(e^tY) idk how to put Y in terms of W given the conditional probability statement of the question as an input....

Comment: "If it just asked to find $\mathbb E(Y)=\mathbb E(g(W))$" - but that is what you are being asked, with $g(w) = e^{w(e^t-1)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[ e^{tY}\mid W\right] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nt} \frac{e^{-W}W^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-W}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(We^t)^n}{n!}\right)\\
&=e^{W(e^t-1)}\\
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}
M_Y(t) &= \mathbb E\left[e^{tY}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{tY}\mid W \right]\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{W(e^t-1)} \right]\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{x(e^t-1)}\beta e^{-\beta x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \beta e^{-x(\beta - e^t + 1)}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac\beta{\beta - e^t + 1},
\end{align}
for $t<\log(1+\beta)$.

Comment: I believe in the first row there is a typo, expression should stand on its own rather than be inside the expected value function.

Comment: @ak87 Thanks, I forgot to change that when I was revising the post.

Comment: This was a multi-part question. On one of the followups, it asks to compute the limit of the MGF of βY (that is, of Y/(E(Y)) as β goes to zero. But MβY(t)= MY(βt) by MGF properties which gives me β/(β−e^βt+1) whose limit is obviously zero rather than the MGF of some other distribution as the question implies. Could you please point out what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: $$\lim_{\beta\to0} \frac\beta{\beta-e^{\beta t}+1} =\ ? $$